# How to pass basic authentication using Wapiti

Tags: wapiti

I am trying to pass basic authentication header using Wapiti but I'm getting 401 from the xml report.

I am using the following command line;

python wapiti  --auth-method basic 'authorization':'Basic

Comment: headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'authorization': 'Basic ' + config.authorization
    }

Comment: python wapiti http://<url> --auth-method basic -r authorization: Basic

Comment: Basically what I need to do is to pass authorization:Basic (identity provider).   python wapiti http:url --auth-method basic authorization:Basic UID